# Android unity3d image path

Tags: android, image, path, unity-game-engine, itext

I am trying to get an instance of an image in Unity that is in:

> /assets/texture/image.png

Here is what I did:

```
path = Application.persistentDataPath;
path2 = Application.dataPath;
path3 = Application.streamingAssetsPath;
iTextSharp.text.Image imageHeader = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("jar:file://" + path2 + "!/assets/texture/image.png");
```

I did try with all the paths, and I am getting:

> NotSupportedException:
>   jar:file:/data/app/com.myapk!/assets/texture/image.png.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

To access a file in the assets folder of your apk:

```
String path = getAssets() + "/texture/image.png";
iTextSharp.text.Image imageHeader = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(path);
```

The path should be something like:

```
file:///android_asset/texture/image.png
```

EDIT: Can't use getAssets in Unity - Then there will not be a direct system-mounted file path for files in the assets folder.

What I usually do for C++/NDK applications with graphical assets is to decompress the assets directory to the SDCard to have a direct path access. On first launch of the app, you extract your assets folder to /mnt/sdcard (getExternalStorageDirectory) then use that. Otherwise I have no Idea how to do it in Unity directly, but there must be something.

Comment: I can't use `getAssets()` in Unity

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this easy on yourself, put your texture in the `Resources/` folder and use Resources.Load to load it.  Or put it in `StreamingAssets/` and use the WWW class to load if from the jar file.